# Определить коэффициенты квадратного уравнения

Tags: java

У меня есть поле, в котором пользователь вводит уравнение вида ax^2+bx+c.
Допустим, пользователь ввёл 6x^2-2x+3
Мне нужно вывести коэффициент a(6),b(-2) и c(3).
Также пользователь может вводить -2x+3+6x^2
Все это на Java

Comment: Собственно в чем вопрос, что именно не получается?

Comment: Как программе понять где a,b,c? Допустим я в поле введу 5x^2-7x+2. Как программе понять где какой коэффициент

Comment: пользователю не нужно воодить все уравнение, поскольку вы рассматриваете типовое квадратное уравнение,а оно всегда одинаковое. вводите только 3 числа - а,в,с.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы пользователю было трудно ошибиться, а Вам легче разобраться, где что, сделайте так, чтобы он вводил только коэффициенты в трёх окошечках, а степени X подпишите правее их, примерно так:

[..] x<sup>2</sup> + [..] x + [..] = 0